# Drawable resource not found, but present

Tags: java, android

I am trying to port Halo into Cyanogenmod 11. My device is xhdpi.
The build went fine and it even boots, but causes systemui crash with this log->

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875): Process: com.android.systemui, PID: 1875
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateHalo(BaseStatusBar.java:472)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.start(BaseStatusBar.java:448)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar.start(PhoneStatusBar.java:562)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.SystemBars.createStatusBarFromConfig(SystemBars.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.SystemBars.onNoService(SystemBars.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.ServiceMonitor.startService(ServiceMonitor.java:228)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.ServiceMonitor.access$000(ServiceMonitor.java:49)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.systemui.statusbar.ServiceMonitor$1.handleMessage(ServiceMonitor.java:73)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1875):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  662): Process com.android.systemui has crashed too many times: killing!
```

In the file "BaseStatusBar.java", the line number 472 refers to this part of code:

```
protected void updateHalo() {
    mHaloActive = Settings.System.getInt(mContext.getContentResolver(),
            Settings.System.HALO_ACTIVE, 0) == 1;

  //THE LINE BELOW IS LINE 472
    mHaloButton.setImageResource(mHaloActive ? R.drawable.ic_notify_halo_pressed : R.drawable.ic_notify_halo_normal);

    if (mHaloActive) {
        if (mHalo == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            mHalo = (Halo) inflater.inflate(R.layout.halo_trigger, null);
            mHalo.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null);
            WindowManager.LayoutParams params = mHalo.getWMParams();
            mWindowManager.addView(mHalo, params);
            mHalo.setStatusBar(this);
        }
    } else {
        if (mHalo != null) {
            mHalo.cleanUp();
            mWindowManager.removeView(mHalo);
            mHalo = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Simply according to this, I think the resource (that is icons) "ic_notify_halo_pressed" and "ic_notify_halo_normal""should be present in drawable-xhdpi folder right? And yes they are. But it still gives error.

Also, ic_notify_halo.xml (inside drawable folder) has following content->

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_notify_halo_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_notify_halo_normal" />
</selector>
```

In case you want to have a look at BaseStatusBar.java-> http://pastebin.com/nTp2a0wX

I am really not able to find the issue, please help.

Another thing, earlier while compiling/building rom, compiler was giving me this error->

```
frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/BaseStatusBar.java:1270: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Resources
location: class com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar
        Resources res = mContext.getResources();
        ^
```

But I fixed it by adding the import line-> `import android.content.res.Resources;` (it was just a guess, but compiler than didnt give me any error). I hope this is not related to problem.

Comment: mHaloActive is null? Put a breakpoint and check please

Comment: Sry for being a noob (still learning, started quite recently), but how do I do that? I do know what are breakpoints and have used them in java (in netbeans) and C, but how do I use it here?

Comment: did you initialize mHaloButton?

Comment: lol, I think I didnt. I will try it. No idea how I just kept looking at drawable resources and never cared about button itself! Thanks

Comment: if you are using AndroidStudio, [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html) helps